# Login to Azure AD application with Certificate downloaded from KeyVault

Tags: c#, blazor, certificate, azure-keyvault

I am using AAD application login with certificates, and in dev (#if DEBUG) I use a certificate stored on my local computer.

However, moving to Azure I want to download the certificate from Azure Key Vault. But I have run into some problems.

My code, whom instantiate a graphServiceClient

```
CertificateClient client = new(new Uri("keyvaulturi"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
X509Certificate2 downloadCertificate = client.DownloadCertificate("certname");
                    
var certcredoptions = new ClientCertificateCredentialOptions() { AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud };

var clientCertCredential = new ClientCertificateCredential("TenantID", "ClientID", downloadCertificate, certcredoptions);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientCertCredential, Scopes[]);

return graphClient;
```

Some suggested that I should specify version, however that did not work either.
I suspect that this is due to password, and I tried to make some code instantiating a new X509Certificate2 with an "unlocked" certificate, but failed.

Any help, suggestions, will be appreciated.

### Edit

After adding some logging lines in code it looks like it's not able to retrieve the certificate from Key Vault. The exception text "could be better" IMHO.

Message: One or more errors occurred. (Fatal error at LoginByKeyVaultCert The system cannot find the file specified.) Fatal error at LoginByKeyVaultCert The system cannot find the file specified. The system cannot find the file specified.

Exception type: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException

Failed method: Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates.CertificateClient.DownloadCertificate

I have tried to give all everything under Access policies in the Key Vault, without any luck.

I have recoded local dev to use azure key vault, and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was obviously looking in the wrong direction.

Added to Azure Functions Configuration -> App Settings
WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES = 1

And it just worked.